Word Api office.js - Position of bookmark
I'm using Word's client api, Office.js
After reading a certain bookmark via its name with the function
var bookmark = context.document.getBookmarkRangeOrNullObject("BOOKMARK");

Is it possible to obtain the return of the start and end position of the bookmark within the document? And also the Word reference page
Thanks in advance

Bookmarks don't have a fixed position or page location because the position varies depending on the paper size, orientation, margin settings, and other factors.

With automation COM in c++ I could do this thing :
range = m_document.Range(COleVariant(lPosStart), COleVariant(lPosEnd));
With office.js is not possible ?
